# ng-click is not working in angular js

Tags: html, angularjs, angularjs-ng-click

I am using angular js one of my project and I call "ng-click" function as below

```
<a ng-click="logout'{{x.ParentEntityId['#text']}}')" target="_blank">{{x.Title["#text"]}}</a>
```

In "x.ParentEntityId['#text']" value is "7560183E-1C37-40FE-BACC-8A5B5021FBD7"

When my page load I am getting below error.

[image]

When I passed static value in logout function it working perfectly. Like as below

```
<a ng-click="logout('hi')" target="_blank">{{x.Title["#text"]}}</a>
```

Logout function as below:

```
$scope.logout = function (item) {
                    alert('logout' + item);
                };
```

Please let me know if I am missing something.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In `ng-click` you are in the angular context, so you haven't to use `{{}}`. 
Your ng-click: `logout'{{x.ParentEntityId['#text']}}')` is syntactically incorrect, missing a `(`.
It should be like `ng-click="logout(x.ParentEntityId['#text'])"`.

Answer (score 3):

hey man, I think you error is clear, in the ng-click directive as you wrote


`<a ng-click="logout'{{x.ParentEntityId['#text']}}')"...>`


so, after logout is missing the ( sign for the function and I think you wont need to create an expression {{}} inside the function parameter because on the angular directives you dont need to send the value inside {{}} because it knows it is a variable and it will receive the values as logout('something').

so for example you need to put as below:

 `<a ng-click="logout(x.ParentEntityId['#text'])" target="_blank">{{x.Title["#text"]}}</a>`